# Determinant of the sum of matrices: $\det (A + B^T) = \det(A^T + B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How can you show that $$ \det(A + B^T) = \det(A^T + B)$$
for any $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prove that $$(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$$ and that

$$\det A^T=\det  A$$

and you're done. For the second one, consider expanding the determinant "column-wise" in one case, and "row wise" in the other. In fact, you can use the cofactor expansion of the determinant to prove the claim by induction.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** we have $(A^T+B)^T=A+B^T$

Answer (score 3):

$$\det(A)=\det(A^T)$$

$$\det(A + B^T) = \det((A+B^T)^T) = \det(A^T +B)$$